# Function containing if with or

Tags: julia

I have a function that returns different functions depending on the value of an integer `i`. Some values of this integer return the same function but I am unsure how to implement this. The function was formerly:

```
function myfunc(x,i::Int)
    if i == i_A
        return funcA(x)
    elseif i == i_B
        return funcB(x)
    elseif i == i_C
        return funcB(x)
    elseif i == i_D
        return funcB(x)
    else
    throw(DomainError(i, "Error"))
end
```

which I have unsuccessfully tried to abbreviate to:

```
function myfunc(x,i::Int)
    if i == i_A
        return funcA(x)
    elseif i == i_B || i_C || i_D
        return funcB(x)
    else
    throw(DomainError(i, "Error"))
end
```

What is the proper syntax for multiple 'or' in a julia if loop?

Comment: possibly (not knowing julia): `elseif i == i_B || i==i_C || i==i_D`? You usually don't "OR" the values, but the tests

Comment: There is a missing `end` in your function, after the `throw`. As for the the condition, you could also write `elseif i in (i_B, i_C, i_D)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you can use:

```
function myfunc(x,i::Int)
    if i == i_A
        return funcA(x)
    elseif i == i_B || i == i_C || i == i_D
        return funcB(x)
    else
        throw(DomainError(i, "Error"))
    end
end
```

Or you can use the keyword `in` like this:

```
function myfunc(x,i::Int)
    if i == i_A
        return funcA(x)
    elseif i in [i_B, i_C, i_D]
        return funcB(x)
    else
        throw(DomainError(i, "Error"))
    end
end
```

I personnaly prefer the latter because it is easier to read, and easier to edit.
You can even change your test dynamically by making the array `[i_B, i_C, i_D]` a variable and change its content dynamically.

Comment: It's better to use `(i_B, i_C, i_D)` instead of `[i_B, i_C, i_D]` otherwise this function allocate each time it is called. It's not a big deal, but there is no need to introduce extra allocations when it is so easy to avoid them.